# React toggle checkbox not toggling

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to wrap content in my React app to use a different top-level element.

In my state I have defined `wrapContent: false`

I have defined a toggleWrap method.

```
toggleWrap = () =>  {
this.setState(state => state.wrapContent = !state.wrapContent);
}
```

And finally in my input checkbox I have included the toggleWrap method in

```
onChange={this.toggleWrap}
```

Unfortunately when I run my code, pressing on the checkbox does not wrap my component content in the following code inside my wrapContent method

```
wrapContent(content){
return this.state.wrapContent
? <div className="bg-secondary p-2">
<div className="bg-light"> {content} </div>
```

which wraps the contents of my render(){} return in this component.

What is strange is that when I manually change `wrapContent: false` in my state to True, I see that the checkbox is checked in my browser and that the code within my render is properly wrapped.
So it seems that just my toggleWrap function is not working as it should.

Could someone help here?

**Full code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ValidationDisplay } from './ValidationDisplay';
import { GetValidationMessages } from './ValidationMessages';

export class Editor extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.formElements = {
      name: { label: "Name", name: "name", validation: { required: true, minLength: 3 } },
      category: { label: "Category", name: "category", validation: { required: true, minLength: 5 } },
      price: { label: "Price", name: "price", validation: { type: "number", required: true, min: 5 } }
    }
    this.state = {
      errors: {},
      wrapContent: false
    }
  }
  // 06.11.21- method is invoked when the content is rendered
  setElement = (element) => {
    if (element !== null) {
      this.formElements[element.name].element = element;
    }
  }

  // handleChange = (event) => {
  //   event.persist()
  //   this.setState(state => state[event.target.name] = event.target.value);
  // }

  handleAdd = () => {
    if (this.validateFormElements()) {
      let data = {};
      Object.values(this.formElements)
        .forEach(v => {
          data[v.element.name] = v.element.value;
          v.element.value = "";
        });
      this.props.callback(data);
      this.formElements.name.element.focus();
    }
  }

  validateFormElement = (name) => {
    let errors = GetValidationMessages(this.formElements[name].element);
    this.setState(state => state.errors[name] = errors);
    return errors.length === 0;
  }

  validateFormElements = () => {
    let valid = true;
    Object.keys(this.formElements).forEach(name => {
      if (!this.validateFormElement(name)) {
        valid = false;
      }
    })
    return valid;
  }
    
      toggleWrap = () => {
this.setState(state => state.wrapContent = !state.wrapContent);

      }
    
  wrapContent(content) {
    return this.state.wrapContent
      ? <div className="bg-secondary p-2">
        <div className="bg-light"> {content} </div>
      </div>
      : content;
  }

  render() {
    return this.wrapContent(
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="form-group text-center p-2">
          <div className="form-check">
            <input className="form-check-input"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.wrapContent}
              onChange={this.toggleWrap} />
            <label className="form-check-label">Wrap Content</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        {
          Object.values(this.formElements).map(elem =>
            <div className="form-group p-2" key={elem.name}>
              <label>{elem.label}</label>
              <input className="form-control"
                name={elem.name}
                autoFocus={elem.name === "name"}
                ref={this.setElement}
                onChange={() => this.validateFormElement(elem.name)}
                {...elem.validation} />
              <ValidationDisplay
                errors={this.state.errors[elem.name]} />
            </div>)
        }
        <div className="text-center">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleAdd}>
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? It's a little confusing where you're trying to render/compose logic from these snippets.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Since you are new and the posted code is confusing, is it possible that you reproduce it on https://codesandbox.io/ ? I am sure you can find help here, as long as your question is well asked, read also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @crevulus Full code posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with how you update the state

Try below

```
  toggleWrap = () => {
    this.setState({ wrapContent: !this.state.wrapContent });
  };
```

or

```
  toggleWrap = () => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return { ...state, wrapContent: !this.state.wrapContent };
    });
  };
```

instead of

```
toggleWrap = () => {
   this.setState(state => state.wrapContent = !state.wrapContent);
}
```

Comment: @user17348873, check this out!!

Comment: thanks it works now with the first solution you suggested. But could I ask what I was doing wrong and how you knew how to fix it? 
For me it seemed like my solution should work....

Comment: @user17348873, when you provide a `callback` to `setState` method it needs to return a JSON containing the updated state(`return { ...state, wrapContent: !this.state.wrapContent }`) you need to have next. You were doing an assignment instead(`state.wrapContent = !state.wrapContent`).

Comment: @user17348873, can you please mark this as the answer if this solved your issue?

Comment: Of course. thanks again have a great day :)